# changing a textview text color based on a percentage

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I have to show progress in the number Text-view text itself.Is their any such built in API to paint characters as in the below image?
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/RomainPiel/Titanic you can use this type of library

Comment: it's only animate whole text but not according to getting percentage.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar kind of implementation in my project. 
I dont know what you have used for those clickable images below but when your trigger on change of that selection you can change image by using this function:

```
profileRatingImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.img_strength_01);
```

But here you have to create 8 separate images for the word "COMPLETE".

Comment: no not at all supposed i m getting 5% then only C character fill half with RED color how's that posiblity.

Comment: Oh then it will be 16 images. I thought in minimum at least one letter will be filled.

Comment: BRO bro think about the complexity of the programme Mr. khan

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString) to style strings in a TextView. It allows a TextView to provide different colors and styles to different areas of text. Below is the sample code snippet for your reference

```
    SpannableString styledString
      = new SpannableString("Large\n\n"     // index 0 - 5
           + "Bold\n\n"          // index 7 - 11
           + "Underlined\n\n"    // index 13 - 23
           + "Italic\n\n"        // index 25 - 31
           + "Strikethrough\n\n" // index 33 - 46
           + "Colored\n\n"       // index 48 - 55
           + "Highlighted\n\n"   // index 57 - 68
           + "K Superscript\n\n" // "Superscript" index 72 - 83 
           + "K Subscript\n\n"   // "Subscript" index 87 - 96
           + "Url\n\n"           //  index 98 - 101
           + "Clickable\n\n");   // index 103 - 112

     // make the text twice as large
     styledString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, 5, 0);

     // make text bold
     styledString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 7, 11, 0);

     // underline text
     styledString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 13, 23, 0);

    // Give the styled string to a TextView
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(styledString);
```

[Check this out](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.com/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html) to see the complete code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is only animate a text-view but i want according to percentage.

Comment: You can dynamically change the color using SpannableString based on percentage. That's just a basic logic whenever your percentage changes do the above operation and change the span.

Comment: but suppose how can i do like C this is a character fill half of this character colour not to full ??